# SQL partial duplicates

Tags: sql, duplicates

I have this table :

My initial table contains some duplicates :

```
Product_id   Product_Name   Price_Per_Kg
-----------------------------------------
    1        Banana              0.0
    1        Banana              0.25
    2        Strawberry          0.0
    3        Coconut             0.10
```

I would like to remove the records with the 0.0 value if the same record exists with a value higher than 0.0 for Price_Per_Kg :

```
Product_id   Product_Name   Price_Per_Kg
-----------------------------------------
    1        Banana              0.25
    2        Strawberry          0.0
    3        Coconut             0.10
```

How can I achieve this in SQL ?

Comment: `delete` statements are quite vendor-specific. Please tag your question with the database that you are using: mysql, oracle, sql-server...?

Comment: Show us what have you tried so far ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this below

`SELECT Product_id, Product_Name, MAX(Price_per_kg) 
FROM Product
GROUP BY Product_id, Product_Name`

But what will be required if there are more than one values that are non 0.0 kg ?

Answer (score 0):

you can write a query as:

```
select P.Product_id,P.Product_Name, P.Price_Per_Kg
from @Product P
where exists
(select * from 
   @Product P1 
   where P.Product_id = P1.Product_id
   group by P1.Product_Name,P1.Product_id
   having max(P1.Price_Per_Kg)< = P.Price_Per_Kg)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `NOT EXISTS` like this:

```
select * from Product p 
where p.Price_Per_Kg > 0
or ( 
  p.Price_Per_Kg = 0
  and not exists (
    select 1 from Product
    where Product_id = p.Product_id and Price_Per_Kg > 0
  )  
)
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/kvh2cHvGzHNoS3Wbedpb1U/2).

```
| Product_id | Product_Name | Price_Per_Kg |
| ---------- | ------------ | ------------ |
| 1          | Banana       | 0.25         |
| 2          | Strawberry   | 0            |
| 3          | Coconut      | 0.1          |
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use ROW_NUMBER() function.The query will return the rows with highest price for 
 each product.

```
   SELECT * FROM 
   (
   SELECT 
    ProductID,
    ProductName,
    Price_per_Kg,
    ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY ProductID ORDER BY Price_per_Kg DESC) AS RowNumber
   FROM
   Product
   )Product_Dedupe 
   WHERE RowNumber=1
```